# Visible code markup in profiles

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

When I look at a user's profile, I see this:

[image]

Comment: It's also visible when looking at your own profile.

Comment: -1 for no freehand circles (let's just get that out of the way).

Comment: @BSMP Oh, for some reason I thought I didn't see it on my own. Double-checking, you're right.

Comment: I visited Meta, just to report this.

Comment: This is an awesome bug. lol

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That one slipped through the cracks.

Fixed in the next build.